# Shared Preference Accessibility across Versions of Android

Tags: android, api, sharedpreferences

In API:28
I have a piece of code where I am using Shared Preference to store the value if ringtone is set as:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences("sounds", CONTEXT_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = prefs.edit();
e.putInt("sound_set", 1);
```

If the user upgrades to API 29, via OTA, will this shared preference be still stored/accessible in the code?
Like in code of API 29, if I check :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getSharedPreferences("sounds", CONTEXT_PRIVATE);
if (prefs.getInt("sound_set", 0) == 0){
..
}
```

Will this code access the previously created Shared pref in API 28, or it will create a new one?

P.S: I am new to Android, trying to explore. Please comment only with suggestions/help.

Answer (score 2):

Shared preferences are only cleared if the user completely uninstall the app or delete their data.